# Prove that X=Y is equivalent to P(X)=P(Y),where X,Y are sets and P(X) is Set of X's all subsets.The same goes for P(Y0

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Well,i haven't tried anything yet,because I've got no idea how to prove it.If possible,please help me

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332130/prove-that-mathcalpa%E2%8A%86-mathcalpb-if-and-only-if-a%E2%8A%86b and many many many others which you can find in the "Linked" section (on the right side of the screen) in both the duplicate and the question suggested in this comment.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Note that $\bigcup P(X)=X$.